# Order of evaluation for conditional operator

Tags: c, c11

It is known that both assignment `=` and conditional `?:` operators have right associativity. In following code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d;

    a = b = c = d = 1;
    1 ? a++ : b ? c++ : d;

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

the assignment:

```
a = b = c = d = 1;
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = (b = (c = (d = 1)));
```

and correspondingly:

```
1 ? a++ : b ? c++ : d;
```

is the same as:

```
1 ? a++ : (b ? c++ : d);
```

What the Standard say about this last case? Does it guarantee that such combined expression is evaluated from left to right (so the `c++` part is not evaluated), just as opposite to assignment?

Comment: Right-to-left operator, with precedence 15. Just like =.
See the table of operator precedence http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @MichelBillaud umm.. there is a significant difference in c and c++ in this case, IIRC. This is tagged as C.

Comment: You're right, @NatashaDutta. In C the precedence of ?: is only 13, less than = (15). http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The evaluation order of `?:` is guaranteed: the first operand is evaluated first, then evaluate the second or the third operand depending on whether the first operand is true.

You are mainly confused about the relationship between **operator precedence/associativity** and **order of evaluation**. They play different roles. The former decides how operators are grouped, while the latter decides which sub-expression is evaluated first.

Consider the expression `a * b + c * d`, the precedence rule means it's equivalent to `(a * b) + (c * d)`. But is it guaranteed that the compiler will evaluate `a * b` before `c * d`? The answer is no, in this example, the operator `+` doesn't guarantee the order of evaluation.

The conditional operator `?:` is one of the few operators that do have a specified order of evaluation. (The rest are `&&`, `||`, and `,`).

---

In your example

```
1 ? a++ : b ? c++ : d;
1 ? a++ : (b ? c++ : d);
```

are always equivalent, in both expressions, `1` is evaluated first, and since it's true, `a++` is evaluated next, the end.

Comment: One question, if i replace 1 with 0, will it be same for both the above cases?

Comment: @NatashaDutta Yes, they are still the same, which is guaranteed by the operator precedence/associativity. In that case, `a++` is not evaluated, but `b ? c++ : d` is.

Comment: Sorry, if i am sounding stupid, but can you please tell why it won't execute like `(0 ? a++ : b ) ?  c++ : d;`, considering the `0` case

Comment: I mean to ask, if i use `0`, why the value of `b` won't be considered as the first expression of the second ternary?

Comment: @NatashaDutta Your confusion is just like OP's, think about it for a minute. I added an example of unspecified order of evaluation.

Comment: @NatashaDutta: The syntax of a conditional expression is either a `logical-OR-expression` or `logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression`  Thus, `a ? b : c ? d : e` will always be grouped as `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`, regardless of `a`'s value.  If you want to interpret it as `(a ? b : c) ? d : e`, then you need to use parentheses.

Comment: @JohnBode That `conditional-expression` part clears my doubts. Looking into `6.5.15` now. :-)

Comment: @YuHao I'm confused again, by your latest edit. `But is it guaranteed that the compiler will evaluate b * c before a`...is it not? with or w/o parenthesis, `*` has more precedence over `+`, so `b *c` must execute first, as normal arithmetic rule, isn't it?

Comment: @NatashaDutta In the place of `a`, `b`, and `c` in that example, they could be expressions themselves. Here's another example: `(i++) + (i++) * (i++)`, which `i++` evaluattes first? It's not specified. (Since you are reading the standard, this means there's no **sequence point**). So this expression has undefined behavior. I should probably put this in the answer instead.

Comment: @YuHao One second, `i++` thing is UB because the side effect on `i` is not sequenced, right? But, in case, we use something like `(i++ + j++ * K++)` it will be valid and `j++ * k++` will be evaluated first, right? `i,j,k` are different variables, for sake of argument.

Comment: @NatashaDutta Sure, it's not necessarily UB. The order of evaluation doesn' t matter in most cases. For example, `(1 + 2) * (3 + 4)`, it's not specified whether  `1 + 2` is evaluated first, or `3 + 4` is evaluated first. When both of them are evaluated, the operator `*` is evaluated.

Comment: 1) which one is `necessarily UB`? 2) how about `(1 + 2) + (3 + 4) * (5 + 6)`...after all the `()`s have finished execution (in whichever order maybe), still, the result will look like `3 + 7 * 11` and the result will be `80`. Am I wrong? where is UB then?

Comment: @NatashaDutta Oops, that's a typo, I missed a *not*, now it's fixed.

Comment: @NatashaDutta: `i++ + j++ * k++` is well-defined because we are not attempting to modify an object more than once between sequence points, nor are we attempting to modify *and* use an object in a computation without an intervening sequence point (such as in `a[i]=i++`, which is undefined).  However, it is not guaranteed that `j++ * k++` will be *evaluated* before `i++`.  All that's guaranteed is that the *result* of `j++ * k++` will be added to the result of `i++`,

Answer (score 3):

*Associativity* and *precedence* do not define *order of evaluation*. These concepts are completely unrelated. Order of evaluation in C is defined by *sequencing* rules, not by precedence or associativity.

It is true that `a = b = c = d = 1;` is *associated* as `a = (b = (c = (d = 1)));`, but that does not mean that `d = 1` should be evaluated first, especially in C language, where assignment operator evaluates to an rvalue.

Associtivity simply says that `c` should receive value `1` converted to the type of `d` ("as if" it was read from `d`). But that does not mean that `d = 1` should be done first. In your example all variables have the same type, which means that the whole thing is equivalent to `a = 1; b = 1; c = 1; d = 1;` in absolutely any order. There's no sequencing inside `a = b = c = d = 1` expression.

The same logic applies to `?:` operator. Its associativity simply tells you which operand belongs to which operator. And the grouping is indeed `1 ? a++ : (b ? c++ : d);`. But associativity does not tell you anything about the order of evaluation. Order of evaluation in `?:` operator is defined separately and independently: the condition is always evaluated (sequenced) first, then one (and only one) of the branches is evaluated. In your example `1` is evaluated first, then `a++` is evaluated and its result becomes the result of the entire expression. The `(b ? c++ : d)` part is not even touched.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 ? a++ : b ? c++ : d;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (1) {
    a++;
}
else {
    if (b) {
        c++;
    }
    else {
        d;
    }
}
```

So, the output will be

```
2 1 1 1
```